# Spring MVC webapp + REST: Authorization issue

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-rest

I'm building a CRM system with Spring MVC. Now I'm adding REST support for the system but Spring Security for some reason will allow an unauthorized user with the role "EMPLOYEE" access to the POST method (to create a new customer in the system).
Everything works properly with forms and authentication. Just the authorization fails for some reason specifically for the RestController.

I'm using PostgreSQL to store customers and users as well as for authentication.

Note: I'm using "/customer" for REST and as an entry point for webapp forms.

Here's my SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/customer").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/customer").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/customer/showForm*").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/customer/save*").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/customer/delete").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/customer/**").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
            .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout().permitAll()
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied")
            .and()
            .csrf().disable();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return auth;
    }
}
```

And here's my RestController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/customer")
public class CustomerRestController {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerService customerService;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Customer> getCustomers() {
        return customerService.getCustomers();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{customerId}")
    public Customer getCustomer(@PathVariable int customerId) {
        Customer customer = customerService.getCustomer(customerId);
        if (customer == null) throw new CustomerNotFoundException("Customer not found: id = " + customerId);
        return customer;
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Customer addCustomer(@RequestBody Customer customer) {
        customer.setId(0);
        customerService.saveCustomer(customer);
        return customer;
    }
}
```

Update:

1. I tried mapping RestController to another path - did not work.
2. I also tried splitting SecurityConfig into multiple entry points - did not work and also started to auto login for some reason.
3. Added @Secured({"ROLE_MANAGER", "ROLE_ADMIN"}) before Post method in RestController - same result.

It seems that with my RestController Spring does not care about roles of the users at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of research and trial and error, everything works as desired.
The key problem was the missing asterisks in paths for methods. Instead of "/customer" it has to be "/customer/**".
I have also changed the path a bit for web forms and REST support to avoid confusion and make support easier.
Anyhow here is the updated SecurityConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider auth = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        auth.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        auth.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return auth;
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Bean
        public AuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint() {
            return new CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint();
        }

        @Bean
        public AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler() {
            return new CustomAccessDeniedHandler();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable().antMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/customers/**").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/customers/**").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "ADMIN")
                .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint())
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(accessDeniedHandler())
                .and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(2)
    public static class FormSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/customer/showForm*").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/customer/save*").hasAnyRole("MANAGER", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/customer/delete").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/customer/**").hasRole("EMPLOYEE")
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authenticate")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/access-denied");
        }
    }
}
```